# Strapi didn't run on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, strapi

Strapi version - 4.4.7
Node version - 16.13.1
AWS EB platform - Node.js 16 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.7.0
NODE_ENV - production

Locally all works fine, but after deploying the code with AWS CodePipeline onto the ElasticBeanstalk instance - the project can't be started.

Amazon Linux 2/5.6.4 - works fine
After migrating to Amazon Linux 2/5.7.0 - not working

.buildspec.yml content

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16
    commands:
      - echo node -v
      - node -v
      - echo update npm...
      - npm install -g n -f
      - n 16.13.1
      - npm update -g npm
      - echo node -v
      - node -v
      - echo npm -v
      - npm -v
      - echo install yarn...
      - npm install -g yarn
      - echo yarn -v
      - yarn -v
      - echo Adding docker...
      - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2&
      - timeout 60 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 3; done"
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Installing dependencies...
      - yarn
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building...
      - yarn build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - "Procfile"
    - "package.json"
    - "yarn.lock"
    - "node_modules/**/*"
    - "build/**/*"
    - "src/**/*"
    - "database/**/*"
    - "config/**/*"
    - "data/**/*"
    - "public/**/*"
    - "favicon.ico"
    - ".platform/**/*"
    - ".ebextensions/**/*"
```

An error after running yarn start:

```
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: Require stack:
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: - /var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/strapi
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:15)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:866:27)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093:19)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/strapi:14:21)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1191:14)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1245:10)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:32)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:904:12)
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: requireStack: [ '/var/app/current/node_modules/.bin/strapi' ]
Mar 12 08:55:08 ip-172-31-26-92 web: }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by removing `node_modules` from CodeBuild artifacts and running yarn install in `prebuild` .platform hook